How to calculate the intersection area between polygons in MySQL
I have a table parcels where I store polygons in a column. I'm trying to find all parcels that intersect with a user-provided polygon and calculate the intersection area in square meters.
The table:
CREATE TABLE `pacels` (
`uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:uuid)',
`geometry` polygon NOT NULL /*!80003 SRID 25830 */ COMMENT '(DC2Type:geography_polygon)',
PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
SPATIAL KEY `idx_geometry` (`geometry`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Here is my query:
   $sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT *, ST_AsBinary(geometry) AS geometry, "
    . "ST_Area(ST_Intersection(geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((%s))', 25830))) AS overlap_area "
    . "FROM parcels "
    . "WHERE ST_Intersects(geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((%s))', 25830)) ",
    $polygon,
);

The SRID of all polygons in the table and the provided polygon is 25830. There is a spatial index on the geometry column. I'm using Mysql 8.0.40
When I include the overlap_area in the query, I get the following error:
SQLSTATE[22S01]: <<Unknown error>>: 3516 POLYGON/MULTIPOLYGON value is a geometry of unexpected type GEOMCOLLECTION in st_area.

If I remove the ST_Area calculation, the query runs fine and returns the intersecting parcels, but I obviously can't calculate the intersection area.

How can I correctly calculate the intersection area?
Is 25830 the correct SRID for this use case? Most parcels are located in mainland Spain, and the operations I need to perform involve intersection queries and area calculations.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

ST_Intersects() only checks if two geoms have at least one common point.
ST_Intersection() generates a geometry that is an intersection of two source geoms.
https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#idm9419

Thank you, but that dosn't address any of my questions.
